# Array to string conversion not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, eval, string-conversion

I am trying to print out this code in a string.

```
var x = [[1, 2, 3, 4.5, 6], [7, 8.5, 9.5, 10]];`
console.log(x.toString());
```

This is what shows up.

[image: String Array]

When I print out the regular string, like so-

```
console.log(x);
```

This is what shows up-

[image: Array]

Is there any way I can print out a string with the square brackets? I want the result to be something like `"[[1, 2, 3, 4.5, 6], [7, 8.5, 9.5, 10]]"`.

I need to add this value to a `eval` function, which is why I need to add the entire array (as a string with the brackets) to the function.

Is there any way this can be possible (preferably without additional libraries)?

Comment: Why are you using `eval`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills the eval function doesn't have to do with the question- but I said that anyway to state why exactly I needed to have the array in a string. I am using eval to assign this value to a variable, but instead the first image shown above is being assigned to the variable, which is causing many errors. This is why I am using eval.

Comment: What do you need `eval` to assign it to a variable instead of just assigning the array to the variable? I know that `eval` doesn't have to do with your specific question, but I'm thinking it's a possible XY problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use `JSON.stringify` to convert the Array to a JSON Array.

```
var x = [[1, 2, 3, 4.5, 6], [7, 8.5, 9.5, 10]];
console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
// [[1,2,3,4.5,6],[7,8.5,9.5,10]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with string concatenation.

```
'[' + x.map(e => '[' + e + ']') + ']'
```

```js
var x = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4.5, 6],
  [7, 8.5, 9.5, 10]
];

var string = '[' + x.map(e => '[' + e + ']') + ']';
console.log(string);
document.body.innerHTML = string;
```

**If the elements of the main array are not always array**, [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) can be used with [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
'[' + x.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? '[' + e + ']' : e) + ']'
```

```js
var x = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4.5, 6],
    [7, 8.5, 9.5, 10],
    'name',
    10
];

var string = '[' + x.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? '[' + e + ']' : e) + ']';
console.log(string);
document.body.innerHTML = string;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JSON.stringify()` to serialize x into a string.

`console.log(JSON.stringify(x))` will return what you're looking for.

```
 console.log(JSON.stringify(x))
 [[1,2,3,4.5,6],[7,8.5,9.5,10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the json.stringify() method.The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.
MAy the below url help you where you can get complete reference.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify